# Getting dynamic line breaks in HTML

Tags: html, sql

I am using SQL query along with HTML so that the output comes in desired style and border. Just after the output I am using Text lines. But the problem is output of the query is dynamic; it can any number of rows from 1 to 10. As of now I am giving 10 line breaks so that I can accommodate for the maximum number of rows. But is there anything so that the text line come automatically comes according to the number of rows.

Piece of code is as follows:
Select distinct ''||DATE||''||MODULE||'' from my_table union all

Output of this can be variable number of rows.

After this the text line comes.

Comment: what server side language are you using? any example code? please provide us example and tag.

Comment: I am using select query with list aggregation same as the piece of code provided. Do you need the whole query because it's too long?

Comment: Can I get my text to uses just after the sql output ends ?

Answer (score 0):

Select listagg(kp) within group (order by 1) from 
(Select  as as kp from dual union all
Select  From dual union all
.
.
 After this the code provided in the question is there..